# SQL joining confusion in same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

[image]

```
;WITH People AS 
(
    SELECT 1 as id, 'Ahanda' as name, 20000 as salary, 3 as manager_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Mahfuj', 30000, 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Mr. John', 15000, NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Mr. Tom', 18000, NULL
)
```

Now I want this type of output find the name of the person who has a manager and his manager's salary is more than 17000.

I have tried with this SQL

```
SELECT P.name 
FROM People P 
INNER JOIN People Q ON P.id = Q.manager_id
WHERE Q.salary >= 17000
```

But the the answer is

[image]

But from the values of the table it will be only row number 2 of the `People` table and the answer will be `Mahfuj`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Got it the wrong way round, your join has the logic backwards. You want to join the manager id from table 'P' to the id of table 'Q'

```
SELECT 
P.name 
FROM  People P 
INNER JOIN People Q 
ON P.manager_id = Q.id
WHERE q.salary>=17000
```

P.S. I love that the managers get paid less than their employees.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the query as below :

```
SELECT P.name FROM People P INNER JOIN People Q ON P.manager_id = Q.id WHERE Q.salary >= 17000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT P.NAME
FROM People P
INNER JOIN People Q ON P.manager_id = Q.ID
WHERE Q.salary >= 17000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change JOIN statement:

```
SELECT P.name 
FROM People P 
INNER JOIN People Q 
    ON Q.id = P.manager_id
WHERE Q.salary>=17000
```

Output:

```
name
Mahfuj
```